# Positioning of a 3D camera model in Blender to match the view of a camera object

Tags: modeling, camera

Say I have a IMX477 Mini High Quality Camera Module as a 3D model and want to place it at the exact same position I have my camera object in blender, with the same focal length and sensor size, to get the same view. Does the center of the sensor of the 3D model has to be at the position of the camera object?

Comment: yes it does need to be there.

Comment: Why would you have it in another place? Can you tell a littele bit more?

Comment: I positioned 4 cameras in blender in such a way that I can stitch the resulting views of a certain area. So slight offsets would probalby ruin the stitch. Besides that I was wonder if the angle of view (focal length) starts at the sensor or the lens since lenses with same focal length might have different physical dimensions (not sure if true).