# Finding a camera position based on an image and a 3d model of the same scene

Tags: 3d-view, camera, transforms

I'm new here, I really hope what I'm asking is possible, thanks for your help in advance.

I have an image from a security camera and a photogrammetry 3D model of the same scene. I want to find the exact position of the camera in Blender using tie points on an image and on the model, so that I'll able to reconstruct objects exactly as they were in the scene.

there is a question with a similar idea, but no answer:
[Positioning of a 3D camera model in Blender to match the view of a camera object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/241900/positioning-of-a-3d-camera-model-in-blender-to-match-the-view-of-a-camera-object)

I've tried to use the camera view to fit the camera specs exactly, but I always seem to have a little bit of parallax. I'd like to find a "mathematical" way to do it. As I see it, I have 8 variables to contend with: X, Y, Z, Pan, Tilt, Rotate, focal length (given 18mm fisheye, but that's not exact), and lens distortion.
I tried to pinpoint the exact position using COLMAP, but it won't register.
I would have tried to use fSpy if I could, but I do not have coherent strait lines in the frame to save my life. only random round bricks on the ground near the camera, a lot of plants and trees in the midground, and distant buildings in the background.

I want to use tie points - so I'll be able, for example, say - this brick is on the model here, and on the image there, and so on... for a number of tie points, until I have the correct perspective (XYZ, PTR and focal length) so I'll be left with only lens distortion to contend with. Automatic algorithms that I tried (SFM based) do not work.

Is there a solution for this weird problem?

Thanks again.

Comment: how does your image look like? If the perspective lines are coherent enough you can use fSpy, have you tried it?

Comment: Maybe you will get close to the real camera footage, but the problem is that real cameras might have specifications you can enter in Blender, but real cameras will never have the exact values given in the specifications and different lenses even with the same specifications can be built different and have varying results. The camera in Blender is virtual and uses the specifications as if the lens was built perfect or in some way standardized and optimally shaped.

Comment: @moonboots Thanks for the suggestion, I'll edit the question to be more specific, I would have tried to use fSpy if I could, but I do not have a coherent strait lines  in the frame to save my life. only random round bricks on the floor near the camera, a lot of plants and trees in the midground, and distant buildings in the background.

Comment: you're right, @GordonBrinkmann the real problem is probably optical distortions, but if I can get 95% there, I think it'll be good enough. I can't seem to find a simple solution to the problem, even though it's mostly solved. I want to use tie points - so I can, for example say - this brick is on the model here, and on the image there, and so on...